# Voxel Tree Generator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voxel

My challenge is to randomly generate a voxel tree that looks something like these: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdjpB.jpg (not my own voxel work in photo)

For now i'm Just looking for ideas on how best to approach creating the trunk. I was thinking I'd start with setting the width and height of the the trunk and add each block at coordinate positions layer by layer with some degree of randomness as to where exactly the blocks are placed.

Any thoughts and suggestions are appreciated - for now i'm looking to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make a recursive function to generate the voxel tree.
It would take 3 arguments:

- A vector representing the base of the current node
- A vector representing the extent of the node
- A 3-dimensional array of booleans, which represents the cells of the tree which are filled by the algorithm.
- A counter, to limit the recursion depth

In Unity3D C#, it would look like:

```
void fillTree(Vector3 base, Vector3 extent, bool[,,] output, int depth)
```

And the first call to this recursive function would be

```
bool[,,] output = new bool[sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ];
fillTree(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, output, 0)`.
```

This function will then:

- Check that `depth` is not greater than the maximum, else return
- Using a voxelization algorithm, write `output` with a capsule going from `base` to `base + extent`, with a thickness equal to something like `0.5^depth`, so that each subtree is twice less thick as its parent (This can be pretty hard, so if performance is not a problem, just iterate naively over the whole grid, filling all voxel whose distance to the line segment `[base; base + extent]` is less than the thickness. Don't forget to map the float coordinates to the grid coordinates, by adding to each component of the vector the half of the grid size in the same dimension)
- Choose a random number of subtrees (>= 2)
- For each subtree :

  - Set a random horizontal angle `alpha` to be close to the horizontal angle of the parent, which can be retrieved using `atan2(extent.z, extent.x)` (Beward, an angle is cyclic, so 1 is considered as close to 359)!. The greater `depth` is, the closer the new angle must be from the parent one (the range must be proportional to something like `0.5^depth`, the same as the thickness).
  - Set a vertical angle `beta` to be less than the vertical angle of the parent tree, so that branches seem to fall (the vertical angle of the parent can be computed as `atan2(extent.y, sqrt(extent.x*extent.x + extent.z * extent.z))`)
  - Compute the extent of the subtree, `newExtent` with the coordinates `(cos(alpha)*cos(beta), sin(beta), sin(alpha)*sin(beta))`. Normalize this vector and multiply it with something like `0.5^depth`
  - call `fillTree(base + extent, newExtent, output, depth + 1)`

I have neither tested this algorithm yet, nor implemented it, and it is for sure far less beautiful as what you are trying to achieve, but I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

SpaceColonization might be a good algorithm to check out for this.